# Laravel mix and AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

I'm trying to use [Laravel Mix](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix), which runs webpack, to compile an angular app into one file. I get the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: app is not defined

my `webpack.mix.js`:

```
const { mix } = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/dependencies.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

my `bundle.js` :

```
//load angular
require('angular');

//Load Angular's plugins
require('angular-ui-router');

//Init Angular app
require('./app/app');

//Load angular controllers
require('./app/Controller/aboutController');
....

//Load angular directive
require('./app/Directive/directive');

//Load angular services
require('./app/Services/AccountService');
....
```

My `app/app.js`:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);

app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'app/View/homeView.html',
        controller: 'homeController'
    })
    ...
}]);


app.run(['$state', '$rootScope', function ($state, $rootScope) {
    //APP RUN
}]);
```

I get the `Uncaught ReferenceError: app is not defined`  when I call `app.controller()`, for example `app/Controller/aboutController.js`:

```
app.controller("aboutController", ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', function ($scope, $rootScope, $http) {....}
```

Am i missing something? If i load all the file one by one using `html` it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are defining your app's controller in separate file , then you cannot use directly **app** as there is no reference . You first have to refer to the module .

```
angular.module('app')
  .controller('aboutController'....
```

Let me know if this work for you.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking to do this in a more automated way for their next Laravel project, I created an [article](https://medium.com/@rbrisita/laravel-and-angular-automated-800f342ab3cf) to explain how. Tested on Angular versions 4-7 with Laravel versions 5.4-5.8. I hope it helps!